# Binding Enum to List choice in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to present my Enum cases as a List choice in SwiftUI. I am using Xcode 13.2.1

My problem is binding the state variable of the enum type to the List choice. I get the compiler error
"Generic parameter 'SelectionValue' could not be inferred"

```
enum MyEnum : String, CaseIterable, Identifiable
{
    var id : RawValue { rawValue }
    
    case A = "_A_"
    case B = "_B_"
    case C = "_C_"
}


struct MyView : View
{
    @State var choice : MyEnum = MyEnum.A
    var body : some View
    {
        List( MyEnum.allCases , selection: $choice) // << Generic parameter error here
        { name in
            Text(name.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Attempting to specify the generic parameters does not seem to help me either.

For example I tried

```
List<MyEnum, ForEach<[MyEnum], String, Text>>( MyEnum.allCases , selection: $choice)
```

But get the same compiler error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List` selection type required to be optional. Here is fixed part

```
struct MyView : View
{
    @State var choice : MyEnum? = MyEnum.A      // << here !!

   // .. other content
}
```